# How to download text file from server on local computer in C# framework 2.0.?

Tags: c#-2.0

How to download text file from server on local computer in C# framework 2.0. ?

- My requirement is to read a text file from server and update data in database - But reading file from server line by line will be much slower so I want to copy text file from server to local machine then I will read it and when reading finished will delete a file from local machine.

Also when a connect to server code is executed system should ask for username and password (because I can not hard code doman\username and password in code - server may change)

I know we can do this through 'OpenFileDialog' but I want to do this in background - its also ok if we initially hard code domain, user name and password in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), It also has a [Credentials Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.credentials.aspx).